Fibonacci retracemant and Stop loss and Take profit
I would like to make a script where it draws fibbonaci retracement and puts automatic order (stop loss and take profit) at -0.25 or 1.25 line, also would like that my R/R is always 5, take profit is at 0,25 if starts at 1.25 or take profit is at 0.75 if trade starts at -0.25. Can I get alerts on that setup and can I calculate in script how much I should put usdc to trade considering I use 125x leverage and want my stop loss to be only 25$. I would much appreciate help. Thank you in advance.
I am just starting in pine script and want to make this my first script because I have profitable strategy but don't know where to start my research.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Stackoverflow is not a coding service. To get an answer, you must share your code. What you tried, or reproduce the unexpected behavior.
